# Downcasting with QtRuby

Tags: ruby, qt4

Objects which are not derived from QObject are not downcasted to their dyamic type in QtRuby:

```
require "Qt4"
xml = Qt::DomDocument.new "foo.xml"
xml.setContent(Qt::File.new "foo.xml")
puts xml.documentElement.firstChild.class # Output: Qt::DomNode
```

QtRuby only knows the C++ static type of the object (DomNode) but not the dynamic type of the object (either QDomElement, QDomComment ...): it is not possible to call methods on the dynamic type.

```
puts xml.documentElement.firstChild.nodeType # Output: 1 (ElementNode)
puts xml.documentElement.firstChild.tagName  # method missing for Qt::DomNode
```

Is there anyway to downcast DomNode in order to call methods of DomElement and friends?

Comment: What do you mean "to class methods"? What is it you expect or want to happen specifically?

Comment: Woops, I meant "cast method".

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible, Qt objects which are not derived from QObject can't be upcasted from the Ruby.